# Apache Pulsar Clickhouse Sink - does it have intervals between inserts?

Tags: clickhouse, apache-pulsar

Clickhouse allows high performance writes but only if they are done in bulk and with intervals (recommended is at least 1 second interval between inserts). In the documentation to JDBC connector for Clickhouse batchSize option exists but there is nothing about intervals between inserts and I didn't manage to find insertion logic in the code (I am not a Java guy though).

Does it mean there are no intervals and Pulsar simply does inserts as frequently as it can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about Pulsar.

> recommended is at least 1 second interval between inserts

That recommendation is "one insert per second".
**Nothing about 1 second to sleep.**

This recommendation is too basic and very vague.

Every project is unique, has own environment and requirements.

In one project I insert 10mil. very wide rows **per minute** with RAID 10 with HDD disks.

In another project I do 1000 inserts with ~100 narrow rows each per second using In-memory parts with single NVME disk.